# Cluster color in leaflet Heatmap

Tags: r, leaflet, maps

Is there a way how to have cluster colors in `leaflets` `addHeatmap` function, let say we have some values of variables and cluster them to 8 categories (see example), is there a way how to have also 8 color categories in the `heatMap`? I know this can be done in `ggplot - geom_geom_tile`

Is there a way ho to reproduce it in leaflet as well?

Example:

```
library(ggmap)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)


d = data.frame(
  pred_res = runif(2000, -2, 2),
  lat = runif(2000, 49.94, 50.18),
  lon = runif(2000, 14.22, 14.71)

)
#top&bottom coding and discreting pred_res....8
d$res_coded<-replace(d$pred_res,d$pred_res<(-1),8)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=-1,7)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=-0.4,6)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=-0.1,5)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=0,4)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=0.1,3)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=0.4,2)
d$res_coded<-replace(d$res_coded,d$pred_res>=1,1)

d %>% head
d$res_coded %>% table

library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addHeatmap(lng = d$lon, lat = d$lat, intensity = d$res_coded)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the `gradient` function from the documentation [here](https://bhaskarvk.github.io/leaflet.extras/reference/heatmap.html).

Here is an example with a different color palette:

```
leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addHeatmap(lng = d$lon, lat = d$lat, intensity = d$res_coded, gradient="RdYlGn")
```